# Textarea aparece con texto "invisible"

Tags: html, css

Luego de armar el html y la hoja css, veo que en mi textarea aparece algo escrito pero de forma invisible. Se puede borrar y todo, pero ¿cómo hago para que no aparezca más?

Ahora comparto mi código.

```html
     <form>
        <label
          ><input
            type="text"
            name="first name"
            placeholder="Nombre"
            pattern="^([A-Za-z])+$"
            required
          />
        </label>

        <div>
          <textarea
            placeholder="Deja un Comentario"
            cols="70"
            rows="20"
            maxlength="120"
            required
            style="resize: none"
          >
          </textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
      </form>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Así aparece la imagen, eso resaltado en azul es lo que yo quiero que ya no esté y aparezca así como en la segunda foto. Si a lo resaltado aprieto suprimir, lo borra: es como que hubiera algo escrito. No tiene sentido.
[image: esto es lo raro]
[image: asi debe estar]

Comment: El `placeholder` es el texto que aparece cuando no se ha introducido info.  Para que no se muestre, sólo debes quitar el atributo `placeholder="deja un comentario"`

Comment: si eso es asi pero yo quiero que este el placeholder porque necesito que diga de fondo eso que escribi el problema es otro es muy raro ahora te paso captura

Comment: Bueno, eres bienvenidoo a [edit] tu pregunta y explicarnos con más detalle cuál es el texto intruso :)

Comment: lo e modificado gracias

Comment: Y cuando lo seleccionas, se ve algún caracter? Qué pasa si quitas los espacios y el salto de línea entre las etiquetas `<textarea...></textarea>`?

Comment: no eso es lo raro caracteres no existen y lo que me decis ya lo probe y nada es una locura jamas me habia pasado

Comment: No debes poner saltos de linea en los atributos del text-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba así:

```html
<form>
        <label>
            <input
            type="text"
            name="first name"
            placeholder="Nombre"
            pattern="^([A-Za-z])+$"
            required
          />
        </label>

        <div>
          <textarea placeholder="Deja un Comentario" cols="70" rows="20" maxlength="120" required style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

El text-area es muy especial, si tu dejas saltos de linea o sangrías, los interpretará como espacios. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias muchachos por la buena onda disculpen las molestias muy agradecido estoy aprendiendo son unos genios saludos

Answer (score 1):

Este fragmento replica lo que reportas

```html
<html>
<body>
<form>
        <label
          ><input
            type="text"
            name="first name"
            placeholder="Nombre"
            pattern="^([A-Za-z])+$"
            required
          />
        </label>

        <div>
          <textarea
            placeholder="Deja un Comentario"
            cols="70"
            rows="20"
            maxlength="120"
            required
            style="resize: none"
          >
          </textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
      </form>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este otro no

```html
<html>
<body>
<form>
        <label
          ><input
            type="text"
            name="first name"
            placeholder="Nombre"
            pattern="^([A-Za-z])+$"
            required
          />
        </label>

        <div>
          <textarea
            placeholder="Deja un Comentario"
            cols="70"
            rows="20"
            maxlength="120"
            required
            style="resize: none"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
      </form>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y la única diferencia es, cómo te indiqué, que las etiquetas del textarea no tienen espacio ni saltos de línea entre ellas.

Comment: muchas gracias muchachos por la buena onda disculpen las molestias muy agradecido estoy aprendiendo son unos genios saludos

Comment: @Nacho pa eso estamos, lo importante es que salgamos todos con las dudas resueltas. Recuerda que, si te sirve una respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada en el tick que está a la izquierda de la respuesta, bajo los votos

Comment: gracias soy nuevo pero ire aprendiendo saludos ya marque la que sirve